# function as a parameter to another function error - c++

Tags: c++

I have the following function:

```
CompareType CompareByCitizensNum(const City& c1, const City& c2) {
        if (c1.getNumCitizens() > c2.getNumCitizens()
                || ((c1.getNumCitizens() == c2.getNumCitizens())
                        && (c1.getCityId() > c2.getCityId()))) {
            return BIGGER;
        } else if (c1.getCityId() == c2.getCityId()) {
            return EQUALS;
        }
        return SMALLER;
    }
```

and this is the method that needs to use this function:

```
avlTreeVertix(City newKey, avlTreeVertix* fatherToBe,
            CompareType (*compare)(const City&, const City&)) :
            bf(0), key(newKey), RightHigh(0), LeftHigh(0), vertexesInSubTree(1), father(
                    fatherToBe), childL(NULL), childR(
            NULL), compare(compare) {
        CHECK_NULL(father,);
        if (compare(key, father->key) == BIGGER) {
            //if (isGreater(father)) {
            father->childR = this;
        } else {
            father->childL = this;
        }
    }
```

I tried to call it by the following line:

```
rankTree = new avlTreeVertix(c, NULL, CompareByCitizensNumx);
```

But it says:

> no matching function for call to `wet2::avlTreeVertix::avlTreeVertix(wet2::City&, NULL, <unresolved overloaded function type>)`

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: The function name ends with `Num`, but the function you're passing ends with `Numx`. Is that typo in the real code, or just a copying error?

Comment: Hey, it just a typo but I solved the problem!
Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys, the problem was that the function was a member function, so I needed to add a "static" at the function decleration and now it's working! fool on me..